# Styles are broken on comments section when inserting a part of code with spaces?

Tags: bug, status-review, design, comments

Probably spaces aren't trimmed or trimmed incorrect and comments area isn't limited as well

[image: styles are broken on comments section]

[Link to the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418757/vue-js-loop-with-different-components#comment87853792_50418889)

#### Navigator -> User Agent

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36

Comment: No repro in FF 77.0.1 (Linux Mint)

Comment: ... but reproduced in Chromium 83.0.4103.61

Comment: No repro in Safari version 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2)

Comment: Works fine in [Firefox Nightly 79.0a1 (20200605043926)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuZF4.png), and [Epiphany 3.36.2 (based on WebKitGTK 2.28.2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVaY9.png). Broken in [Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-Bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ9CH.png), and [Chromium Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhlmr.png).

Comment: [Markdown content of that comment](https://tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/) is: `@JohnDoe, I don't understand what you said. probably you need: ⟨backtick⟩<div v-for="item in queue" :key="item.id"><email-queue-item⟨newline⟩⟨26 spaces⟩:item="item"⟨newline⟩⟨26 spaces⟩v-if="type == 'EmailMessage'"></email-queue-item>⟨newline⟩⟨8 spaces⟩<queue-item ⟨newline⟩⟨26 spaces⟩:item="item"⟨newline⟩⟨26 spaces⟩v-else></queue-item></div>⟨backtick⟩`.

Comment: Looks like it’s a known issue: [Large amounts of white-space in code cause comments to overflow in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227187/289905); this was caused by [Multiple spaces in code in comments get merged into one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222376/289905).

Comment: Could be one of the reasons why [comments aren't meant to be used for multiple lines of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255628/215552)...

Comment: Related: [Code in comment overflows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269890/4642212).

Comment: This is caused by `white-space: pre-wrap;` on `<code>`. It looks like this property was added in error.

Comment: Found another example [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm/25965943#comment99631915_25965943) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25965943/14956277).

Comment: And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161311/how-to-do-deep-copy-for-the-below-class-in-java)'s comment, same pre-wrap.

Comment: Yet [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221828/4826740)

Comment: Spaces should be preserved within code blocks, even inline code blocks, as they may be quite relevant to the code. The solution isn't to disable the `white-space` setting, but to change it to `white-space: break-spaces;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, both Chrome and Firefox do undesirable things with the current setting of `white-space: pre-wrap;`. Chrome determines where to place line breaks by looking only at the portion of the text which is actually overflowing and then choosing to break that or not. In the case where it's the spaces at the end of the line, Chrome sees that it isn't supposed to break spaces, so it allows those to overflow the container. An alternative would be to look backwards and break the line prior to the spaces, such that the spaces are on the next line. (continued)

Comment: (continued) This would result in the problem only occurring if the number of spaces exceed the length of a line (i.e. still a problem, but not as severe). Firefox appears to, at least to an extent, break the line earlier, but when it doesn't do that, it collapses a portion of the whitespace at the end of a line, so isn't actually respecting `white-space: pre-wrap;`, as it's not showing all of the whitespace. Both Chrome and Firefox appear to do the correct thing for `white-space: break-spaces;`.