# Broken rendering in comment with code formatting

Tags: bug, specific-question, markdown-rendering

*[How to do deep copy for the below class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161311/how-to-do-deep-copy-for-the-below-class-in-java)*

The code formatting has escaped and gone mad. I am not sure what tag(s) to use.

On desktop, OS X, and Chrome 98.0.4758.102.

[image: Code formatting goes for miles]

Comment: Weird. It's something to do with the data in the comment, if you select the code the part that shoots out is all selectable text.

Comment: @Gimby Hm, hadn't noticed it acts like spaces over there; I thought it was just spans gone wild.

Comment: Dupe: [Styles are broken on comments section when inserting a part of code with spaces?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398119/styles-are-broken-on-comments-section-when-inserting-a-part-of-code-with-spaces)

Comment: @zcoop98 Ah, yep, it's the pre-wrap.